# Not able to work with my filtered items

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

In order to filter an list of objects I've defined this property:

```
 private ICollectionView _view;
    public ICollectionView View
    {
        get
        {
            return _view;
        }
        set
        {
            _view = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("View");
        }
    }
```

And then my filter:

```
  item.View = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(item.myList);

 item.View.Filter = delegate(object o)
 {

           if (myCondition)
      {
         return true;
      }

}
```

The filter works fine but as ICollectionView is an interface I can't work with my items: if I call them this way:

```
element1 = item.View[0].SomeProperty;
```

I recieve

```
Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView'
```

I've tried to set in the beginning `View` not as interface but later I couldn't make the filter work. 
Doing so and trying to cast:

```
item.View = (ICollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(item.myList);
```

Haven't brought me good results either.

What can I do in order not only to filter (in my case I display the items in a ComboBox) but also work with them... My aim is to be able to make a foreach loop for all elements remaining in the ComboBox. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Store the view separately from the list. Shorthand below, fill in with appropiate INotifyPropertyChanged and such.

```
List<SomeType> list;
ICollectionView view;

view = list as ICollectionView;
view.Filter = obj => obj.someprop == somevalue;

list[ 10 ].someprop = somevalue
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to implement it right now, but, I have a question: Is the list changing or it remains the same? If it changes I can bind the list directly to my ComboBox, is this correct?

Comment: If I bind the View there are not items in my ComboBox, and if I bind the list I get an exception that I can't cast the List<SomeType> to ICollectionView. Do you know what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Given List and ICollectionView:

```
List<SomeType> list;
ICollectionView view=CollectionViewSourse.GetDefaultView(list);
view.Filter=filter;
```

You can use

```
var filteredList=view.Cast<SomeType>().ToList();
```

to enable indexer for filtered collection. The list will change with the collection view. Therefore in some way it is not deterministic. I am not sure but quite interested to know what is your use case to force you to use indexer on collection view.